# How to divide ASP.NET projects (web applications) between team members?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Is there any specific way to divide any ASP.NET project between the team members?

I am working in a team and all of us (the team members) are new and each time we have a difficulty with dividing the project between us.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat open ended not knowing your environment, skills, type of project, etc. but a 1000 ft view:

Split the application out into separate components. If you are using TFS one user can shelve their pending work so the others can use it and compile OR you agree to code to particular interfaces which you can mock the data on until another team member is done with their component. Since the interface is generally quick to define, you can immediately start using it and generate a stub class to implement it until the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

> My team also working on Web Application project. We all are working as
>   a team using Repository We are using [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/). Using svn, Team
>   members can use working copy of repository modify their part and commit or update
>   the changes.
> For deviding project, some will work on back end
>   coding(database, stored procedures, webservice etc) and some will work
>   on front end(Design and coding of master screens etc).. Main thing is
>   Clear communication between team members(Ex:use Skype), discuss about
>   project  and divide work  based on  member's expertise and interest
>   of work.